# What causes a cast object type issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a webAPI with Visual Studio 2012. I've followed the provided Microsoft ASP.NET tutorial.

So I've got the class, repository and controller down. The software is able to to run and connect with the database. When I run and make the API call, this error occurs:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[ReservationsAPI.Contact]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ReservationsAPI.Models.Contacts]'.
```

This error occurs in the method below in my repository file:

```
public IEnumerable<Contacts> GetAll()
{
    var ContactsAll = from c in rdbc.Contacts select c;
    return (IEnumerable<Contacts>)ContactsAll;
}
```

The error occurs at the `return` line. I am not sure how to deal with this error.

Comment: if you hover over your `var` with your mouse what type does it show ContactsAll as?

Comment: @WillNewton IQueryable<Contact> = System.Linq.IQueryable<ReservationsAPI.Contact>

Comment: well first, change `<Contacts>` to `<Contact>` in your cast and in your method's return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method's return type, change the type `Contacts` to `Contact` without the `s`. You can see this in the error message that it needs to be `Contact`.